# Modified terminal prompt to show current Git branch, and now (master) is showing up in all directories

Tags: git, bash, terminal

I added the git branch to my terminal and now it is constantly telling me that I am in branch master in all of my directories. I thought maybe git is just installed in my ~ directory, so I ran

```
rm -rf .git
```

But it still shows up.

Here is what I added to my .bash_profile

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Comment: Try `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, which should show you what the `git root` is. From there, you can decide whether you want to remove it.

Comment: thank you! I was just assuming .bash_profile was doing something weird. didnt expect git to be installed that high level. i probably did that a long time ago lol

Comment: Did you use a self written function on purpose? Git already comes with a function for that: `PS1="\w$(__git_ps1) \$ "`.

Answer (score 2):

here is how mine is setup:

```
#git info
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=true 
GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="git auto verbose"

#functions
function __git_ps1 (){
    local b="$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)";
    if [ -n "$b" ]; then
        printf " (%s)" "${b##refs/heads/}";
    fi
}
```

and my prompt is:

```
PS1="[\j]\u@\h \w [\$?]\$(__git_ps1 \"(%s)\") "
```